# MAAS Node not PXE Booting

Tags: boot, maas, pxe

I'm having an issue so far with getting my first node to boot... it connects to the MAAS Server and begins the boot procedure but then hangs because it is unable to find the correct kernel image boot. The error message that i receive is "Could not not find kernel image: amd64/generic/trusty/no-such-image/boot-kernel" the screen then sits at a boot prompt.

I am very new at this and am not sure what files need to be change or where and if i have buggered something up or need to revert it back to its original... someone please give me some guidance as its very unclear every where i have looked online.

Answer (score 3):

this is a known bun in maas 1.5

see https://bugs.launchpad.net/maas/+bug/1307779

i had the same problem and upgraded to 1.6
but this results that its now stuck on route-info

you can upgrade by adding
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:maas-maintainers/stable